# How can I create multiple rows from a single row (sql server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In our organisation we have a central purchasing company (CPC) who then sells to our retail company (Company_X) via an intercompany PO, who then sells on to the customer.
What I need to do is link our retail sale back to the original purchase order.

For example I have a table which contains the following (and a multitude of other columns):

`Company_X_Sales`:

```
InterCO_PO_no  Sales_Order_No  Part_No  Qty
-------------  --------------  -------  ---
12345          98765           ABCD     10
```

I then have a table which has the following:

`CPC_Sales`:

```
PO_Number  InterCO_SO_No  Part_No  Qty
---------  -------------  -------  ---
00015      12345          ABCD     5  
00012      12345          ABCD     2  
00009      12345          ABCD     4   
00007      12345          ABCD     3
```

So you can see that the final sale of 10 items was made up of parts which came from more than 1 external POs in the central company.

What I need to be able to do is replicate the rows in `Company_X_Sales`, include the Original PO Number and set the quantities as in `CPC_Sales`.

I need to end up with something like this:

`Company_X_Sales_EXTD`:

```
PO_Number  InterCO_PO_no  Sales_Order_No  Part_No  Qty
---------  -------------  --------------  -------  ---
00007      12345          98765           ABCD     3
00009      12345          98765           ABCD     4
00012      12345          98765           ABCD     2
00015      12345          98765           ABCD     1
```

I have to use the `Company_X_Sales` as my driving table - the `CPC_Sales` is simply as a lookup to derive the original PO Number.

Hoping you can help I am working through the weekend on this as it is part of a piece of work which has a very aggressive timescale.

I do not mind if the solution requires more than one pass of the table or creation of views if needed.  I am just really really struggling.

Comment: Please show the complete structures of the relevant tables with some sample data and a desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your question, but it sounds like you're trying to make your Company_X_Sales table have 3 rows instead of 1, just with varying quantities?  If so, something like this should work:

```
SELECT S.PO_Number, C.InterCO_PO_no, C.Sales_Order_No, C.Part_No, S.Qty
FROM Company_X_Sales C
   JOIN CPC_Sales S ON C.InterCO_PO_no = S.InterCO_SO_No
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0abfe/1).

That will give you the 4 rows with the correct quantities.  Then you can delete and reinsert accordingly.

To get those rows into the table, you have a few options, but something like this should work:

```
--Flag the rows for deletion
UPDATE Company_X_Sales SET Qty = -1 -- Or some arbitrary value that does not exist in the table

--Insert new correct rows
INSERT INTO Company_X_Sales 
SELECT C.InterCO_PO_no, C.Sales_Order_No, C.Part_No, S.Qty
FROM Company_X_Sales C
   JOIN CPC_Sales S ON C.InterCO_PO_no = S.InterCO_SO_No

--Cleanup flagged rows for deletion
DELETE FROM Company_X_Sales  WHERE Qty = -1
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hi @sgeddes  many thx for replying so quickly.  Yes - you have it spot on with what I am trying to acheive.  This whole piece of work has been a big headache not lease because of poor data integrity.  And the worst thing is it is probably the most high profile piece of work in the company at the moment.  I am going to get a stong coffee and then see if I can work with your code.  I have updated my example and you may see there is added complication as the sum of the quantitied in the CPC table does nat always equal the qty in Company_X_Sales - as I said - nightmare.  :)

Comment: I added S.PO_Number to the results.  However, if you don't have that field in your Company_X_Sales table, you can't store that value there.  Make sense?

Comment: And here is the SQL Fiddle -- looks identical to your desired output.  But again, you'd need that column in your table for it to work.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0abfe/1

Answer (score 0):

```
select [PO_Number],[InterCO_SO_No], Company_X_Sales.Sales_Order_No, [Part_No],[Qty] from CPC_Sales inner join Company_X_Sales on Company_X_Sales.InterCO_PO_no = CPC_Sales.InterCO_SO_no
```

Simple inner join on two tables will get you the required result IMHO.

Comment: Hi @Aniket - I had tried that approach - however if you see the full details, it isnt quite as simple as that unfortunately